# Getting RequestMapping value from HttpServletRequest in Filter or DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I want to get the RequestMapping value from the HTTP Servlet Request either in Filter or Dispatcher Servlet.

For example if the Request Mapping value is "`/api/users/{user_id}/dashboards/{dashboard_id}/`"
And the request URI is `http://localhost:8080/api/users/123123123/dashboards/test?start=2014-12-31&end=2014-12-31`

Then from above mentioned request URI I want to understand what is the corresponding Request Mapping value its getting resolved.

I have tried [URLPathHelper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UrlPathHelper.html) but did not had any luck.

Can this be achieved ?

Comment: You cannot as that isn't available at that moment. It is only available after the request has been inspected by the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` before that there is nothing. Also the mapping is quite complex and there is no such thing as the request mapping as some are bound to objects, or put in a map, others are request parameters. What you can do is in a `HandlerInterceptor` look at the resolved handler. Which for `@RequestMapping` would be a `HandlerMethod`.

Comment: And if you want more information I suggest setting the `org.springframework.web` log level to debug or even trace, that will give you loads of information.